# Java Game Server taking up too much memory!

Tags: java, java-server

I have a Java-based command-line server running that hosts the highscores for a game I made on my website. It works efficiently and fast. However, it takes up about 200MB of RAM! I have tried everything from manually nulling out everything to calling System.gc()

I am starting to suspect that this might have something to do with the input stream and output stream objects that I use from the Socket connection. I have noticed that when I first run the program, it takes up a normal amount of RAM. Then once it gets a connection, it jumps to 100MB and keeps getting higher for each connection.

EDIT: In one of my classes, I hold all the names, scores, and timestamp in 3 different ArrayLists. However, a thorough examination using jhat and jmap showed that combined they only use about 5MB of RAM.

If this is too vague for anyone to answer, ask and I will gladly give the source code.

Comment: If you see it rising with each connection and not falling when clients disconnect, you're probably maintaining references to closed sockets.

Comment: If the JVM is anything like .NET, then "forcing" a garbage collect is not guaranteed to actually collect anything, even if there are unused objects with have no references to them.  Plus, 200M is peanuts when you can buy 24GB RAM for 300$.  Is this really a problem?

Comment: @ide It rises a lot with each connection, then falls a little as they disconnect since I tried to manually null out each reference to all objects before their lives end.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham
I am running this server on a command prompt on my laptop, not on a dedicated server (i wish i had one!)

Comment: @Roi: Well, if you're sure that you're nulling out all references to each socket, you might want to run your JVM with `-Xmx128m` to put some pressure on the GC. It might be that some data structure somewhere is still holding onto your socket references, though...
http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to add one thing, I have a class that holds an 3 ArrayLists instances with about 115000 indices each. They are of types String, Integer and Long. They hold the scores so expect about 5MB of memory from those only. The only thing I'm wondering is where the other 195MB go to. jmap and jhat produce normal results so I'm still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have a leak caused by retaining references to objects beyond their useful life.

I suggest you get a profiler and use it to investigate.  A good and free place start is the VisualVM program that distributes with Java 6.

A profiler is a separate program that either attaches to the JVM or hosts a JVM for your program and monitors the execution of your program.  It can track object allocations and code execution, either statistically or by "instrumenting" the executing code.  It will show you if objects are being allocated and not released, and can show what objects they are and where they were allocated (among many other useful things).

I use jProfiler, which is commercial (but well worth it for a professional).  Last time I searched there were several good quality profilers available for free (at least for personal use).  VisualVM has basic, but useful, profiling capabilities, and I would begin there (on Windows you can find it in the JDK bin directory; I presume the same is true for Linux and Mac).

Comment: Oh yes I have used a profiler before, I just didn't know it was called so :P However, I have never used VisualVM so I will investigate into it for a while. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like all the names and highscores data take up 150MB and the rest is what the JVM needs.

Comment: That's a lot of high-score data - I suspect somethings really off the rails there.

Comment: I know! I only have about 130,000 high scores submitted and the file that stores them is only 3MB. For efficiency purposes, when my server first starts running, I read the file and store all the names and scores in ArrayLists. Why it would take 150MB is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like jmap followed by jhat to see how your memory is actually being used.

Sun's (Oracle's) JVM never releases memory back to the OS, so it's not surprising you see monotonic increase in memory usage.

Comment: jmap histogram option produced normal results, saying there was a total of about 25MB of memory used and almost 500,000 instances. jmap dump followed by jhat also showed normal results.

Comment: @Roi, I would say this is evidence that you don't really have a problem, depending on whether you expect those half million objects to exist.  (Do you?  If not, work your way up the referrer graph in jhat.)  By the way, how are you judging memory usage?  Are you looking at the size of virtual memory allocated to java or are you looking at the size of its resident set?

Comment: The second paragraph is incorrect.  Oracle JVMs *do* release memory back to the OS ... "reluctantly".  See the `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` option.